# How to checked row checked Janus Grid C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, janus

I use janus gridex datagridview, In first column type is CheckBocx, I want to check if current row selected is checked or not, but my code not working

```
if(DBGrid.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckBoxColumn"].Value == true)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the row is '**ActAsSelector = True'** then you can use the row level checking itself :

```
if(DBGrid.CurrentRow.IsChecked)
{
    // do something
}
```

Otherwise you need to cast the value to Boolean.

```
if((bool)DBGrid.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckBoxColumn"].Value == true)
{
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the row is 'ActAsSelector = True', you can use itself :

```cs
var CheckedList = string.Join(",", 
    gridEX1.GetCheckedRows()
        .Cast<Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXRow>()
        .Select(x => x.Cells["ID"].Text)
        .ToArray());
```